# SQLITE3 update after insert trigger will not be created

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I have some troubles with a update after insert trigger in SQLITE.

After an insert on Tab1 I want to Update Tab3 if
- the event, inserted in tab1 is listed on tab2
- and the obj and status of tab3 are also listed on tab2

```
tab1                    tab2                    tab3
date       |  event     event | obj | status    obj | status
-----------+---------   ------+-----+-------    ----+-------
2014-11-29 |   456       456  |  3  |  1         3  | 1
2014-11-29 |   477       457  |  3  |  2         4  | 2 
2014-11-29 |   488       477  |  4  |  1
2014-11-29 |   476       477  |  4  |  2
```

i wrote the folowing create statement for the trigger:

```
create trigger uptab3 after insert on tab1 for each row 
 begin
    update tab3 
    SET status = (SELECT status FROM tab2 WHERE event = NEW.event)
    WHERE obj = (SELECT obj FROM tab2 WHERE event = NEW.event)
 end
```

when i paste this in the commandline, sqlite doesnt return an error but the trigger is not created. Where is my mistake in the statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) shows that all statements in the trigger body must be terminated with a semicolon:

```
create trigger uptab3 after insert on tab1 for each row 
 begin
    update tab3 
    SET status = (SELECT status FROM tab2 WHERE event = NEW.event)
    WHERE obj = (SELECT obj FROM tab2 WHERE event = NEW.event);
 end;
```